# Encode Email to pass to Web.API

Tags: c#, encoding, asp.net-web-api

I am needing to send an email address to a `Web.Api get` method. I need to check to see if the email address exists in our system before allowing someone to sign up for a new account.

My first thought was to `encode` the email address and then `decode` it once it was inside the `Get` Action

The URL looks something like this
    `http://mysite/Api/RTSCredit/jharding%40email.com`

However, This always errors with a 404 response

Here is the `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{emailAddress}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
```

When I send in a simple string `http://mysite/Api/RTSCredit/someemail`

It hits the Get action like I would prefer, but obviously can't return a useful value.

Here is the Get Action

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] string emailAddress)
{
    using (IRtsCreditDal rtsCreditDal = new RtsCreditDal())
    {
        var listOfExistingUsers = rtsCreditDal.GetUsersByEmail(emailAddress);
        if (listOfExistingUsers == null || listOfExistingUsers.Count == 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "not found");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
        }
    }
  }
```

What adjustments do I need to make in order to pass an email to this `Action`?

**As I've been playing further, it doesn't seem to like the `period` in the URL. I could easily do something to replace that character but it feels like a hack.**

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What happens if you use:http://mysite/Api/RTSCredit?emailAddress=enodedaddress?

Comment: 404 with the ? between Credit?emailAddress= and Credit/emailAddress=

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding a trailing / at the end of the email reaching from the client:

```
http://localhost:8800/api/users/user@gmail.com/
```

Comment: This should really be the answer if you want the email in your route vs. in the querystring.

Answer (score 2):

Change your default route back to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Remove the `[FromUri]` attribute from the Action, then you should be able to call your action using the url suggested by Maess:

```
/mysite/Api/RTSCredit?emailAddress=jharding%40email.com
```

Comment: <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Stc.RtsCredit.Web.BuyNow/Api/RTSCredit?mkastle%40rtsfinancial.com'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'RTSCredit' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

Comment: Strange? I copied your code and it tests out ok here with the changes.

Comment: Actually I went back and made the edits again and it works. Not sure what I missed the first time, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to decode your string parameter value.

```
String newEmailAddress = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(emailAddress);
```

That would replace characters like '%' by the characters of your original text.

Comment: This isn't the issue. The problem occurs in model binding from the URL.