# Complement [FromUri] serialization with APIController

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, datetime-format

We have multiple API controllers accepting GET requests like so:

```
//FooController
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]Foo f);
//BarController
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]Bar b);
```

Now - we would like (or, are forced) to change DateTime string format within GET query string **globally**

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" -> "yyyy-MM-ddTHH.mm.ss"
```

After the change all `[FromUri]` serializations with classes containing `DateTime` types fail.

Is there a way to complement `[FromUri]` serialization to accept the DateTime format in query string? Or do we have to build custom serialization for all API parameters to support new DateTime string format?

**EDIT**: example as requested

```
public class Foo {
 public DateTime time {get; set;}
}

//FooController. Let's say route is api/foo
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]Foo f);

GET api/foo?time=2017-01-01T12.00.00
```

Comment: HH.mm.ss -  dots  is cousing extension problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404254/encode-email-to-pass-to-web-api

Comment: Ok, but that's not the point. Let's say the dots would be replaced with -

Comment: if you are using js you can encodeURIComponent the datetime value before passing it in to the controller.  Then the controller will decode and deserialize it.

Comment: @Woot Don't assume the problem is with encoding :

Comment: @supertopi my apologies, couldn't you use a custom parameter binder?  I believe it would require that all your DateTime Parameters have the same property name though.  I haven't ever written one for a Dattime but we did use them for other properties.  http://www.vickram.me/custom-datetime-model-binding-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @Woot I tried it but couldn't get it to work with [FromUri]. Please provide some code if you think it's possible :)

Comment: Could you post an exact URL and the field where you expect it to serialize correctly?

Comment: @AkashKava example added

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844830/web-api-modelbinding-from-uri

Comment: @davidmdem Asp.NET WebAPI (and MVC) version is 5.2.2 with targeted platform net45

Comment: @GeorgeVovos yes I have seen it. It's a different case since the given string passes the default `DateTime.Parse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply this behavior that you want across all DateTime types on all models, then you'll want to write a [custom binder for the DateTime type and apply it globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844830/web-api-modelbinding-from-uri).

**DateTime Model Binder**

```
public class MyDateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(DateTime))
            return false;

        var time = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (time == null)
            bindingContext.Model = default(DateTime);
        else
            bindingContext.Model = DateTime.Parse(time.AttemptedValue.Replace(".", ":"));

        return true;
    }
}
```

**WebAPI Config**

```
config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new MyDateTimeModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks for the write up but the question was about changing the serialization globally and using `[FromUri]` because multiple API parameter classes have multiple attributes.

Comment: Did you see the DateTime model binder at the bottom?  It addresses applying the behavior globally.  I'll edit the post to remove the example addressing the sample code so the actual  answer isn't obscured.