# How to customise the parsing received with FromUri in Web Api 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to customise the way some properties are binded when the webservice tries to parse from a complex type (a class) received through a [FromUri] parameter.

The **controller method**:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult ComplexPropertiesTest([FromUri] MyComplexPropertiesClass parameters)
```

The **class**:

```
 public class MyComplexPropertiesClass
    {
        public DateTime TestTime { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> TestIntEnumeration { get; set; }

        public int SimpleInt { get; set; }

        public string SimpleString { get; set; }

        // More properties...
    }
```

`TestTime` needs to be parsed from strings with `yyyyMMddTHHmmss` date format and only the time part `HHmmss` has to be stored.

`TestEnumeration` can be received as a string like `5,20,50,100,9` and it has to be stored as an `IEnumerable[int]`.

Example of URL:

```
http://www.example.com/test?TestTime=20170303T091500&TestEnumeration=5,20,50,100,9.
```

I’ve tried the `HttpParameterBinding` approach in http://www.vickram.me/custom-datetime-model-binding-in-asp-net-web-api/, but it works only if I change the controller method to something like:

```
public IHttpActionResult ComplexPropertiesTest ([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaSeparatedIntegerCollectionModelBinder))] IEnumerable<int> TestIntEnumeration, …all the other parameters…)`
```

But this is not a good solution because I would need to modify the controller to manually assign every argument to the properties of a new MyComplexPropertiesClass instance.

Also, I’ve attempted the `CommaDelimitedCollectionModelBinder` approach in http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/

```
internal class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val?.AttemptedValue == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

I receive `parameters` in bindingContext.ModelName, but logically there is no `ValueProvider` for `MyComplexPropertiesClass`. I could try to get the values of  `actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query`, but then I would need to manually parse every property and assign the values to a new instance of `MyComplexPropertiesClass` using reflection. I would be nice to parse manually the ones I want, leveraging the default Web Api 2 binding process for the rest.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own JsonConverter? This article may help: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/miziel/2014/09/23/custom-web-api-json-converter-single-property/
Also, I have noticed the interfaces not always work properly, try to change the IEnumerable to List or Array

Comment: Why not to share [what](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) have you tried?

Comment: I tried the JSON approach, but the custom serializer does not get fired because the content is not JSON. The content comes from a `[FromUri]` parameter. 
@SergeyShushlyapin I’ve updated my answer to show what I’ve already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar case with DateTime:

[Complement [FromUri] serialization with APIController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020282/complement-fromuri-serialization-with-apicontroller)

The drawback is that is applied to every DateTime property. You can't choose in which properties you want to use this behaviour. Neither does it solve the problem with the `TestEnumeration`.